# How to send List of dates as part of sql query using SpringTemplate + JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

Well, I have a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE someDate IN (date1, date2, date3);
```

I am trying to construct this using ST (SpringTemplate) and am using JDBCTemplate to make the query.

If I have to pass only one date, I can use :

```
stringTemplateInstance.add("someColKey",dateInstance);
```

But how can I send a list of dates so that the `IN` clause gets it?.

Right now, I am using `StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(dateListForQuery);` to the query ( which I don't like).

Comment: Don't. Ditch the `StringTemplate` and `JdbcTemplate` and use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and use `select * from table where someDate in (:dates)` and then just use the list/array of dates to execute the query.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I could do that.. But this query is being constructed dynamically . The actual query is rather complex and springtempalte makes rendering easy.. :P

Comment: Still don't. Then use the StringTemplate to compose the query but use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to replace the parameters. Never you string concat or the likes to construct queries, as that makes you vulnarable to sql injection attacks. However I still have a hard time to see how `StringTemplate` helps you here if you construct the query along the way, filling a `Map` with named parameters and then finally execute the query. But that could be me...

Comment: @M.Deinum - Okie then .. (sql injection attacks 0=0) . I've got enough evidence to ditch ST for a life time :) . BTW you will have to wait for 5 mins :P

Comment: Well `StringTemplate` can be useful but I doubt the usefulness in this usecase :).

Comment: @M.Deinum - I am reusing some code.. instead of writing my query with `:colValues` that's all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch both the `StringTemplate` as well as the `JdbcTemplate` and switch to the [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html).

```
String query = "select * from table where someDate in (:dates)";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("dates", yourlistofdates);

List<YourResultType> result = template.query(query, params, new YourResultTypeRowMapper());
```

That is all.